# get df indeces as dictionary

Tags: pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am working with multi index pandas dataframes.

My dataframe:

```
                      Value
index1 index2 index3       
1      5      3          20
```

It cames from some filtering and I will always have 1 row.

I would like to get this dict:

{index_name1: index_value1, index_name2: index_value2, ...}

```
{'index1':1,'index2':5,'index3':3}
```

The column has no importance now and I don't want it

Thank you all

Comment: Are your index names always like that or would they have arbitrary names?

Comment: No, this is just an example, they may change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `index.names` are important use `zip` + `dict`:

```
print (df.index.names)
['index1', 'index2', 'index3']

d = dict(zip(df.index.names, df.index[0]))
print (d)
{'index2': 5, 'index3': 3, 'index1': 1}
```

Or seelct no columns, [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) for `DataFrame`, seelct first row and convert to `dict`:

```
d = df = df[[]].reset_index().iloc[0].to_dict()
print (d)
{'index2': 5, 'index3': 3, 'index1': 1}
```

and thanks @Zero for another solution - create columns by `MultiIndex` by [`Index.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_frame.html):

```
d = df.index.to_frame().iloc[0].to_dict()
```

Comment: Also, as `df.index.to_frame().iloc[0].to_dict()`

Comment: @Zero - Thank you ;)

Comment: This one doesn't work: AttributeError: 'MultiIndex' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Comment: OK, I think problem is your pandas version is bellow 0.21.0 - check [`Index.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.to_frame.html) -  `New in version 0.21.0.`

Comment: Oh thanks! Unforntunately I cannot update pandas. Btw nice to know